# move button from right to left on hover with css3 animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to reproduce the effect of the button on the right of [this page](http://www.userreport.com/).

Begin position :

[image]

End position after animation :

[image]

I have done this HTML code :

```
<div id="btnFeedbackHome">
            <div><img src="img/home_feedback.png" id="feedbackImgHomeBtn" /></div>
            <p>Ideas & feedback</p>
        </div>
```

And CSS :

```
#btnFeedbackHome {
    width: 180px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #35BDCF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#btnFeedbackHome p{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#btnFeedbackHome div{
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #2A97A6;
    height: 45px;
}

#feedbackImgHomeBtn {
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
```

For the moment, my code show the end position but i don't know how to do to perform the same translation effect on my div.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Still any queries feel free to ask.

```css
body
{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#btnFeedbackHome {
    width: 180px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    right: -135px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #35BDCF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#btnFeedbackHome p{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#btnFeedbackHome div{
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #2A97A6;
    height: 45px;
}

#feedbackImgHomeBtn {
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
#btnFeedbackHome:hover
{
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btnFeedbackHome">
            <div><img src="img/home_feedback.png" id="feedbackImgHomeBtn" /></div>
            <p>Ideas & feedback</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. But make sure body to have no horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a simple CSS transition on the element. I've created a JSFiddle that builds on your example to show how to do this with no JavaScript as the only thing you need is a `hover` added to the main container. http://jsfiddle.net/cudome3h/1/

If you do everything that you did and just change the CSS to what I have here you will get a similar effect:

```
#btnFeedbackHome {
    width: 180px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    right: -140px;
    background-color: #35BDCF;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#btnFeedbackHome:hover {
    right: 0;
}
```